# doing topsellers/bestsellers by category elegantly

Tags: architecture

So I've been tasked with making a bestsellers box, yet I've heard a horror story about the bestsellers box in a previous site taking down the site because of the extensive load.

First, I should mention that this site has quite a bit of products, somewhere in the thousands or ten thousands.

Ive seen extensions and code snippets that do bestsellers, and it seems to make use of something like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_sold_collection')
                            ->addOrderedQty()
                            ->setStoreId($storeId)
                            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
            ->setDateRange($sellDate['startdate'],          $sellDate['todaydate']) //
                            ->addUrlRewrite()
                            ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
                            ->setPageSize($this->getModel()->getHomepageProductsLimit())
                            ->setCurPage(1)
            ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
```

I looked into that and it seems like whats going on is that its going through all the products, and getting ordered_qty from those products.

I also noticed that there were some cool tables called sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly /  sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily / sales_bestsellers_aggregated_weekly that get populated by a cron task.

I thought it would be cool to make use of these tables, but the problem with that is A) there is no category data and B) its monthly/daily/weekly rather than all time.   That latter may not be such an issue, but its something to be considered.

I guess what I am looking for is some thoughts on how to approach this in a way where its not going to take down the site.   The site will be behind varnish, but I heard even behind varnish, the last site was taken down by bestsellers.

Thanks!

Comment: I think what I am going to do is join catalog_product_category with this bestsellers monthly table and use that.  Seems like a good way of going about it.  I believe the client can be convinced this is the best way to go.

Comment: If the query runs reasonably fast against your production db, I would imagine you'd be ok querying the non-aggregated db tables in your block. I'd just be sure to have a decent cache lifetime for that block.

Comment: please add and contribute to this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105698/magento-getting-store-bestsellers-configurable-products-only-from-current-stor and the code that is being created here https://github.com/seansan/SNH_Addorderqty

Answer (score 1):

The collection shown is actually the Magento-way of doing this. (Sorting once is enough, of course ;) ).

It does not run against all products, it is Magento's way to implement a database query using collections. The "Magento-way" doing the join you want would be the same (pseudo-code):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->join('catalog_category_product as cpp1')->where(...);
```

You can see the executed SQL-statement:

```
echo $collection->getSelect();
```

Ask if u need more help.

Comment: wouldnt it have to get ordered_qty from all products in order to sort it descending?  I dug in the code, and quickly looking at it, it looks like its loading the products, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you something to work with and pulls the top 50 best sellers. I have noticed that daily, monthly, yearly actually don't calculate properly in Magento/DB - not sure which one and they are "ALL TIME" which can be problematic. Anyway I know this is a late reply but for future reference for people who need to query best sellers, this should help. You can replace product_name etc. with * if you like. I just needed the following rows.

```
SELECT product_name, entity_id, product_id, sku, url_path, small_image, SUM( qty_ordered ) AS total
    FROM sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly, catalog_product_flat_1
    WHERE store_id =0
    AND entity_id = product_id
    GROUP BY product_name
    ORDER BY total DESC 
    LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Oh yeah, you can also change sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly to sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily or sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly, but as mentioned they all give the same result for me...