# Magento getting store bestsellers: configurable products, only from current store

Tags: blocks, collection, product-collection

Magento getting store bestsellers: configurable products, only from current store

We have tested some bestseller codes like from [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/bestseller-products-in-magento/comment-page-2/#comment-431917) and [here](https://blog.amasty.com/how-to-display-bestselling-products-in-magento-source-code/) and [here](https://www.zodiacmedia.co.uk/blog/magento-bestselling-products). They all work fine if you *only* sell simple products. We sell many products and often in many stores.

So in essence what we would like is a bestseller list that shows

- configurable bestsellers (or at least the real parent)
- with sales order qty summed per store (so exclude sales made in other stores)
- with sales order qty summed per category (optional)
- with an optional command to lag limit the sales qty over time (like last month only)

Has this ever been done?

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to solve this issue forever we have created a public extension (not solved yet)

https://github.com/seansan/SNH_Addorderqty

We really hope people are willing to contribute to this and solve this issue forever

Comment: do you have this extension for magento 2? Or suggest me other link. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Not a coding answer, but a guide on how some of this can be done using [Dynamic Category Products](http://www.proxiblue.com.au/premium-modules/magento-dynamic-category-products.html) - Full disclosure: This is an extension I created, and sell.

**configurable bestsellers (or at least the real parent)**

This one is easy. Using Dynamic Rules, you can get all the Best Sellers (back X days), and filter out any Simple Products that belong to a Complex Product, displaying the Complex product instead of the simple. This can be filtered by website, meeting the requirement noted: **with sales order qty summed per store (so exclude sales made in other stores)**

You will have a category that lists the Configurable, instead of the simple.

Example rule:

[image]

You can also do this by Profit, revenue and in place of Best Sellers, go with Least Sellers.

[image]

Since the end result is a normal magento category, you can easily create custom code to work from that result (for example excluding products for the date lag you also want)